# How to get indices of a sorted array in Python

Tags: python, indexing, sorting

I have a numerical list:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 100, 5]
```

Now if I sort this list to obtain `[1, 2, 3, 5, 100]`. 
What I want is the indices of the elements from the 
original list in the sorted order i.e. `[0, 1, 2, 4, 3]` 
--- ala MATLAB's sort function that returns both 
values and indices.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851077/how-to-return-index-of-a-sorted-list

Comment: @unutbu This is not a dupe (IMO). The question does not contradict using Numpy.argsort()

Comment: @amit: What do you mean by "does not contradict"?

Comment: @unutbu Numpy.argsort() is a fine answer to this question, it might be a dupe to the other thread linked (which you also closed and I thin you shouldn't have) but not to the one you mentioned, as Numpy.argsort() is fine answer for these two, but NOT for the one you refered to.

Comment: @amit: Please be more specific. Which page is not a dupe? By the way, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382352/equivalent-of-numpy-argsort-in-basic-python is showing how to define a **pure Python function** that *behaves like* numpy.argsort. It does not suggest np.argsort as the answer...

Comment: @unutbu This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7851077/572670 Both should not be dupes of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3382352/572670 - since Numpy.argsort() is valid answer to them, but not to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3382352/572670

Comment: Unfortunately, this question has a severe flaw in its choice of example, as two different ways of reading the question would give the same answer when the input is just a transposition out of sorted order.

Comment: [order vs rank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315622)

Answer (score 288):

If you are using numpy, you have the argsort() function available:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.argsort(myList)
array([0, 1, 2, 4, 3])
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html

This returns the arguments that would sort the array or list.

Comment: Note that  this may not be what you want! See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388972/getting-indices-of-ascending-order-of-list

Answer (score 215):

Something like next:

```
>>> myList = [1, 2, 3, 100, 5]
>>> [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(myList), key=lambda x:x[1])]
[0, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

`enumerate(myList)` gives you a list containing tuples of (index, value):

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 100), (4, 5)]
```

You sort the list by passing it to `sorted` and specifying a function to extract the sort key (the second element of each tuple; that's what the `lambda` is for. Finally, the original index of each *sorted* element is extracted using the `[i[0] for i in ...]` list comprehension.

Comment: you can use `itemgetter(1)` instead of the lambda function

Comment: @gnibbler is referring to the [`itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function in the `operator` module, FYI. So do `from operator import itemgetter` to use it.

Comment: you can get the sorted list and indicies by using zip: `sorted_items, sorted_inds = zip(*sorted([(i,e) for i,e in enumerate(my_list)], key=itemgetter(1)))`

Comment: @RomanBodnarchuk this doesn't work, `x = [3,1,2];
numpy.argsort(x)` yields [1,2,0].

Comment: Adding to @JohnLaRooy, you can use `itemgetter` to do the indexing in both cases, e.g. `sorted_indices = list(map(itemgetter(0), sorted(enumerate(myList), key=itemgetter(1))))`. Alternatively, since indexing is one of those weirdly slow things in Python, you can continue to use the listcomp, and use unpacking instead of indexing: `[i for i, _ in sorted(enumerate(myList), key=itemgetter(1))]`

Comment: @CharlesL. the comprehension in your answer seems pointless. Perhaps you meant to swap `i` and `e`.

Answer (score 93):

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 100, 5]    
sorted(range(len(myList)),key=myList.__getitem__)

[0, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

Comment: [This answer was discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384409).

Comment: One minor note: This will be less efficient when the input is something like `collections.deque`, which [has `O(n)` indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39522920/364696). For standard sequences like `list`/`tuple`, it's perfect (and [faster than other built-in options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57028877/364696)), it's just for weird cases where it's suboptimal. [Roman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6422754/364696) or [my own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75365783/364696), or just converting to `list` once up-front, will work better when that's the case. (To be clear, up-voted this)

Answer (score 50):

I did a quick performance check on these with [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) (a project of mine) and found that it's hard to recommend anything else but

```py
np.argsort(x)
```

(note the log scale):

[image]

---

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import perfplot
import numpy as np


def sorted_enumerate(seq):
    return [i for (v, i) in sorted((v, i) for (i, v) in enumerate(seq))]


def sorted_enumerate_key(seq):
    return [x for x, y in sorted(enumerate(seq), key=lambda x: x[1])]


def sorted_range(seq):
    return sorted(range(len(seq)), key=seq.__getitem__)


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=np.random.rand,
    kernels=[sorted_enumerate, sorted_enumerate_key, sorted_range, np.argsort],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(15)],
    xlabel="len(x)",
)
b.save("out.png")
```

Comment: It's also very nice to see the shortest pure python solution was the fastest as the PEPs intended!

Answer (score 26):

The answers with `enumerate` are nice, but I personally don't like the lambda used to sort  by the value. The following just reverses the index and the value, and sorts that. So it'll first sort by value, then by index.

```
sorted((e,i) for i,e in enumerate(myList))
```

Answer (score 16):

Updated answer with `enumerate` and `itemgetter`:

```
sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[1])
# [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5), (3, 100)]
```

Zip the lists together: The first element in the tuple will the index, the second is the value (then sort it using the second value of the tuple `x[1]`, x is the tuple)

Or using `itemgetter` from the `operator`module`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: enumerate seems more appropriate than zip in this case

Answer (score 10):

Essentially you need to do an `argsort`, what implementation you need depends if you want to use external libraries (e.g. NumPy) or if you want to stay pure-Python without dependencies.

The question you need to ask yourself is: Do you want the

- indices that would sort the array/list
- indices that the elements would have in the sorted array/list

Unfortunately the example in the question doesn't make it clear what is desired because both will give the same result:

```py
>>> arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 100, 5])

>>> np.argsort(np.argsort(arr))
array([0, 1, 2, 4, 3], dtype=int64)

>>> np.argsort(arr)
array([0, 1, 2, 4, 3], dtype=int64)
```

### Choosing the `argsort` implementation

If you have NumPy at your disposal you can simply use the function [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy-argsort) or method [`numpy.ndarray.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argsort.html).

An implementation without NumPy was mentioned in some other answers already, so I'll just recap the fastest solution according to [the benchmark answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57028877/5393381)

```py
def argsort(l):
    return sorted(range(len(l)), key=l.__getitem__)
```

### Getting the indices that would sort the array/list

To get the indices that would sort the array/list you can simply call `argsort` on the array or list. I'm using the NumPy versions here but the Python implementation should give the same results

```py
>>> arr = np.array([3, 1, 2, 4])
>>> np.argsort(arr)
array([1, 2, 0, 3], dtype=int64)
```

The result contains the indices that are needed to get the sorted array.

Since the sorted array would be `[1, 2, 3, 4]` the argsorted array contains the indices of these elements in the original.

- The smallest value is `1` and it is at index `1` in the original so the first element of the result is `1`.
- The `2` is at index `2` in the original so the second element of the result is `2`.
- The `3` is at index `0` in the original so the third element of the result is `0`.
- The largest value `4` and it is at index `3` in the original so the last element of the result is `3`.

### Getting the indices that the elements would have in the sorted array/list

In this case you would need to apply `argsort` **twice**:

```py
>>> arr = np.array([3, 1, 2, 4])
>>> np.argsort(np.argsort(arr))
array([2, 0, 1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

In this case :

- the first element of the original is `3`, which is the third largest value so it would have index `2` in the sorted array/list so the first element is `2`.
- the second element of the original is `1`, which is the smallest value so it would have index `0` in the sorted array/list so the second element is `0`.
- the third element of the original is `2`, which is the second-smallest value so it would have index `1` in the sorted array/list so the third element is `1`.
- the fourth element of the original is `4` which is the largest value so it would have index `3` in the sorted array/list so the last element is `3`.

Answer (score 8):

If you do not want to use numpy,

```
sorted(range(len(seq)), key=seq.__getitem__)
```

is fastest, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6979121/3703716).

Comment: Aside from the variable name, this is a duplicate of [this answer posted seven years prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6423325/364696).

Answer (score 8):

**The other answers are WRONG.**

Running `argsort` once is not the solution.
For example, the following code:

```
import numpy as np
x = [3,1,2]
np.argsort(x)
```

yields `array([1, 2, 0], dtype=int64)` which is not what we want.

The answer should be to run `argsort` twice:

```
import numpy as np
x = [3,1,2]
np.argsort(np.argsort(x))
```

gives `array([2, 0, 1], dtype=int64)` as expected.

Comment: Your claim makes `x[2]` (3) the smallest element, and `x[1]` (1) the largest element (since sorting integers orders them from smallest value to largest value). Also, with the OPs example, a single `np.argsort([1, 2, 3, 100, 5])` yields `array([0, 1, 2, 4, 3])`, which appears to be the indices the OP wants.

Comment: @0 0 your example is a specific case. If we run `arr = [1,2,3,100, 5, 9]
res = np.argsort(arr)
print(res)` then we get `[0 1 2 4 5 3]` which is wrong.

Comment: I'm unclear what is wrong: `arr[res]` yields `array([  1,   2,   3,   5,   9, 100])`, which seems to be perfectly fine, since that resulting array is in (increasing) order.

Comment: @0 0 for `arr=[1,2,3,100, 5, 9]`, I expect the output to be `inds=[0,1,2,5,3,4]`, because this is the order in which you'll order the elements (increasingly) - 1 is in the 0s place, 2 in the 1st place, .... , 5 on the 3rd place and 9 on the 4th place. In order to get that output (`inds`) I need to run `argsort` twice, like I mentioned.

Comment: So those indices are a kind of ranking of the array elements (0th place, 1st place, etc). Given the OP's mention to [MATLAB's `sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html), I reckon the OP wants the other functionality, much like `np.argsort` is normally used (where one can use `arr[np.argsort[arr]]` to obtain the sorted array, as in the last MATLAB example). Your answer applies to [this case / question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284646/rank-items-in-an-array-using-python-numpy-without-sorting-array-twice) instead.

Answer (score 3):

**Most easiest way you can use Numpy Packages for that purpose**:

```
import numpy
s = numpy.array([2, 3, 1, 4, 5])
sort_index = numpy.argsort(s)
print(sort_index)
```

**But If you want that you code should use baisc python code:**

```
s = [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
li=[]
  
for i in range(len(s)):
      li.append([s[i],i])
li.sort()
sort_index = []
  
for x in li:
      sort_index.append(x[1])
  
print(sort_index)
```

Answer (score 2):

We will create another array of indexes from 0 to n-1
Then zip this to the original array and then sort it on the basis of the original values

```
ar = [1,2,3,4,5]
new_ar = list(zip(ar,[i for i in range(len(ar))]))
new_ar.sort()
```

`

Answer (score 2):

```
s = [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
print([sorted(s, reverse=False).index(val) for val in s])
```

For a list with duplicate elements, it will return the rank without ties, e.g.

```
s = [2, 2, 1, 4, 5]
print([sorted(s, reverse=False).index(val) for val in s])
```

returns

```
[1, 1, 0, 3, 4]
```

Comment: What if `s` contains duplicates?

Comment: The method returns the rank without ties if there are duplicated elements.

Answer (score 1):

Import numpy as np

**FOR INDEX**

```
S=[11,2,44,55,66,0,10,3,33]

r=np.argsort(S)

[output]=array([5, 1, 7, 6, 0, 8, 2, 3, 4])
```

argsort Returns the indices  of S in sorted order

**FOR VALUE**

```
np.sort(S)

[output]=array([ 0,  2,  3, 10, 11, 33, 44, 55, 66])
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly convert your list to this:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 100, 5]
```

add a index to your list's item

```
myList = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 100], [4, 5]]
```

next :

```
sorted(myList, key=lambda k:k[1])
```

result:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5], [3, 100]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
s = [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]
li = []

for i in range(len(s)):
    li.append([s[i], i])
li.sort()
sort_index = []

for x in li:
    sort_index.append(x[1])

print(sort_index)
```

Try this, It worked for me cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A variant on [RustyRob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6423325/364696) (which is already [the most performant pure Python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57028877/364696)) that may be superior when the collection you're sorting either:

1. Isn't a sequence (e.g. it's a `set`, and there's a legitimate reason to want the indices corresponding to how far an iterator must be advanced to reach the item), or
2. Is a sequence without `O(1)` indexing (among Python's included batteries, `collections.deque` is a notable example of this)

Case #1 is unlikely to be useful, but case #2 is more likely to be meaningful. In either case, you have two choices:

1. Convert to a `list`/`tuple` and use the converted version, or
2. Use a trick to assign keys based on iteration order

This answer provides the solution to #2. Note that it's not guaranteed to work by the language standard; the language says each key will be computed once, but not the order they will be computed in. On every version of CPython, the reference interpreter, to date, it's precomputed in order from beginning to end, so this works, but be aware it's not *guaranteed*. In any event, the code is:

```
sizediterable = ...
sorted_indices = sorted(range(len(sizediterable)), key=lambda _, it=iter(sizediterable): next(it))
```

All that does is provide a `key` function that ignores the value it's given (an index) and instead provides the next item from an iterator preconstructed from the original container (cached as a defaulted argument to allow it to function as a one-liner). As a result, for something like a large `collections.deque`, where using its `.__getitem__` involves `O(n)` work (and therefore computing all the keys would involve `O(n²)` work), sequential iteration remains `O(1)`, so generating the keys remains just `O(n)`.

If you need something guaranteed to work by the language standard, using built-in types, [Roman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6422754/364696) will have the same algorithmic efficiency as this solution (as neither of them rely on the algorithmic efficiency of indexing the original container).

To be clear, for the suggested use case with `collections.deque`, the `deque` would have to be quite large for this to matter; [`deque`s have a fairly large constant divisor for indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39522920/364696), so only truly huge ones would have an issue. Of course, by the same token, the cost of sorting is pretty minimal if the inputs are small/cheap to compare, so if your inputs are large enough that efficient sorting matters, they're large enough for efficient indexing to matter too.

Answer (score 0):

a little confused for me.

The question is about "How to get indices of a sorted array in Python", I was understanding that How to get sorted indices of each elements in array.

So give my solution for someone who may need:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 100, 5]
b = [m[0] for m in sorted([j for j in enumerate([i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x:x[1])])],key=lambda x:x[1])]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you'll often want to get the sorted values as well as the indices. Here's quick and nice way to do that (which doesn't waste time sorting everything twice):

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 100, 5]
```

```
indices, values = zip(*sorted(enumerate(myList), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

```
>>> indices
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> values
(1, 2, 3, 5, 100)
```