# sort a python list based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have a list whose elements are dictionaries with a value and a type field, i.e.:

```
my_list = [{'val':5, 'type':0},{'val':6, 'type':2},{'val':2, 'type':1},{'val':9, 'type':0}]
```

I would like to sort this list in descending order based on the `type` field and within each type based on the `value` field, and obtain a vector with the corresponding indexes of the sorting along with the sorted vector.

I know how to do it for an individual criteria using a `lambda` function, i.e.:

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda k: k['type'], reverse=True)
```

but how do I extend it to multiple criteria?

**Desired output**:

```
 sorted_list = [{'val':6, 'type':2},{'val':2, 'type':1},{'val':9, 'type':0},{'val':5, 'type':0}]

 sorted_idxs = [1, 2, 3, 0]`, such that `[my_list[k] for k in sorted_idxs]==sorted_list
```

Comment: Once you have the indexes, you can generate the sorted list yourself. The reverse isn't true.

Comment: And the answer that the duplicate doesn't give you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422700/how-to-get-indices-of-a-sorted-array-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the `key` returns a tuple, `sorted` will consider them in order when sorting:

```
In [3]: sorted(my_list, key=lambda k: (k['type'], k['val']), reverse=True)
Out[3]:
[{'type': 2, 'val': 6},
 {'type': 1, 'val': 2},
 {'type': 0, 'val': 9},
 {'type': 0, 'val': 5}]
```

If you want the indices, just throw an `enumerate` in there as well:

```
In [7]: sorted(enumerate(my_list), key=lambda k: (k[1]['type'], k[1]['val']), reverse=True)
Out[7]:
[(1, {'type': 2, 'val': 6}),
 (2, {'type': 1, 'val': 2}),
 (3, {'type': 0, 'val': 9}),
 (0, {'type': 0, 'val': 5})]

In [8]: [k for k, v in sorted(enumerate(my_list), key=lambda k: (k[1]['type'], k[1]['val']), reverse=True)]
Out[8]: [1, 2, 3, 0]
```

Comment: `sorted_ids, sorted_list = zip(*[(i, x) for sorted(enumerate(my_list), key=lambda j, d: (d['type'], d['val']), reverse=True)])` can seperate the two into seperate lists