# Keeping track of original indicies when sorting a list of lists by length

Tags: python, list, sorting, nested-lists

You can sort a list of lists by length as follows:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [1,2,3]
l3 = [1,2]
lists = [l1, l2, l3]
sorted_lists = sorted(lists, key=len)
print sorted_lists  #[[1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
```

I can't figure out how to keep track of the indicies to then match up the contents of `sorted_lists` with the original list names `l1`, `l2` and `l3`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6422754/4025404) gets close, but I'm not sure how the solution can be implemented when sorting by length.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is very possible. Just modify the key a bit to specify the right predicate on which `len` is to be applied.

```
>>> lists = [l1, l2, l3]
>>> lists = sorted(enumerate(lists), key=lambda x: len(x[1])) # enumerate is a tuple of (index, elem), sort by len(elem)
[(2, [1, 2]), (0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [1, 2, 3])]
```

Comment: Can anyone come up with a `lambda`-free solution for this?

Comment: ... `def key_func(x): return len(x[1])` :)

Comment: It's like I learned nothing from my last question. Lol. Thanks.

Comment: @Coldspeed For `lambda` free solution, how about using `arg.sort()` from `numpy`?

Comment: @open-source Perfect, thank you. I do believe there is no vanilla one liner without using `lambda`. Numpy is the only other way to go. `>>> np.argsort(lists); array([2, 0, 1])`

Comment: @Coldspeed I just used `list comprehension`  for it, just for reference I posted the answer, I don't know how efficient it would be though.

Answer (score 1):

Using `arg.sort()` from `numpy` with `list comprehension` can be other way:

```
import numpy

new_list = [(index, lists[index])for index in numpy.argsort(lists)]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[(2, [1, 2]), (0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [1, 2, 3])]
```

Comment: Seems fine. As for speed, they'd both be the same since they both internally run on C routines.