# variable = Variable without changing value

Tags: python

My Question is i have two list one is sorted and the another not so how can i get the not sorted index that eqaul to the sorted one

```
from math import sqrt as sq

Points = [(54,0), (4,6), (-1,6), (5,-7), (5,1)]

def closeest() :

    a= list(int(sq(x[0]**2 + x[1]**2)) for x in Points)

    a.sort()
    print("The new list is:")
    print(a)
    print("The closest point is:")
   # Here i need to get the value of Points index that equal to the first sorted a list
```

closeest()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get indices of a sorted array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422700/how-to-get-indices-of-a-sorted-array-in-python)

Comment: I dont understand can you give me a full code

Comment: The previous message is automatically generated when I noted that your question is a duplicate of a previously answered question.  You are asking how to do an argsort in python.  Take a look at the question and answer in the link.

Comment: it dosnt work it just give me the orignal array like 0 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Add `print([i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x:x[1])])` before `a.sort()`

Comment: still the same i need (54, 0) instead of the sorted

Answer (score 1):

Use your "distance" function as the `key` argument for whatever sorting function you use.

```
>>> Points = [(54,0), (4,6), (-1,6), (5,-7), (5,1)]
>>> from math import sqrt as sq
>>> dist = lambda point: int(sq(point[0]**2 + point[1]**2))
>>> max(Points, key=dist)
(54, 0)
```