# Sort list of complex numbers and get sorting indexes

Tags: python, sorting, complex-numbers

I need to sort a `list` of complex numbers by the imaginary parts. I found the solution on the question “[sorting list of complex numbers](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/852540-sorting-list-complex-numbers)”.

Simply using the sorted command with the appropriate key:

```
list_ordered = sorted(list, key=lambda x: x.imag)
```

I'd also like to get back the sorting indexes. [Another existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422700/how-to-get-indices-of-a-sorted-array-in-python/6423325) doesn't work in the case of complex numbers. Is there an elegant solution to extract the indexes in my case?

Thanks!

Comment: What are "sorting indexes"? You have multiple lists (input, output, intermediate in some algorithms) involved, and this could refer to the indexes of items in any of them. Clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [second answer to the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6422754/550094) can easily be adapted:

```
complexes = [1, 2+3j, 1-2j, 6+1j]
[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(complexes), key=lambda x:x[1].imag)]

# [2, 0, 3, 1]
```