# numpy: find index in sorted array (in an efficient way)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to sort a numpy array and find out where each element went.

[`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) will tell me for each index in the sorted array, which index in the unsorted array goes there. I'm looking for something like the inverse: For each index in the unsorted array, where does it go in the sorted array.

```
a = np.array([1, 4, 2, 3])

# a sorted is [1,2,3,4]
# the 1 goes to index 0
# the 4 goes to index 3
# the 2 goes to index 1
# the 3 goes to index 2

# desired output
[0, 3, 1, 2]

# for comparison, argsort output
[0, 2, 3, 1]
```

A simple solution uses [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

```
np.searchsorted(np.sort(a), a)
# produces [0, 3, 1, 2]
```

I'm unhappy with this solution, because it seems very inefficient. It sorts and searches in two separate steps.

This fancy indexing fails for arrays with duplicates, look at:

```
a = np.array([1, 4, 2, 3, 5])
print(np.argsort(a)[np.argsort(a)])
print(np.searchsorted(np.sort(a),a))


a = np.array([1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 2])
print(np.argsort(a)[np.argsort(a)])
print(np.searchsorted(np.sort(a),a))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to [invert the permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11649577) that sorts the array. As shown in the linked question, you can do that like this:

```
import numpy as np

def sorted_position(array):
    a = np.argsort(array)
    a[a.copy()] = np.arange(len(a))
    return a

print(sorted_position([0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 0.5, 0.8, 0.4, 0.7, 0.3, 0.9, 0.6]))
# [1 2 0 5 8 4 7 3 9 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `argsort` twice on the list.
At first the fact that this works seems a bit confusing, but if you think about it for a while it starts to make sense.

```
a = np.array([1, 4, 2, 3])
argSorted = np.argsort(a) # [0, 2, 3, 1]
invArgSorted = np.argsort(argSorted) # [0, 3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Did you forget tho pass something to the second call of `argsort`? You could improve the answer by explaining how it works and why it make sense :)

Comment: I and others have suggested this double argsort without elaborate explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54388972/901925