# how to get an array of numpy and return an array with the index?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

How could I use an array from numpy and return an array with the index of each sorted element of the original array?

For example, In: `[10, 5, 13, 2]`, and I expect the Output will be `[2, 1, 3, 0]`.

The "argsort" function doesn't work for me, because it returns an output that I don't want (Output [3 1 0 2]), that is it sorts inside and returns the array but with the elements sorted, and I need it with the order of the original array.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459554/numpy-find-index-in-sorted-array-in-an-efficient-way. Basically: you can use **two** calls to `argsort` to do this. (Notice how in your example, `np.argsort([3, 1, 0, 2])` would give `[2, 1, 3, 0]` which is your intented output.)

Comment: Do you have to use numpy? This is trivial for a plain Python list