# How to get indices of sorted array in descending order

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a simple list of values of which I need the index sorted by the original value order (max to min).

Let's assume the list is

```py
maxList = [7, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3]
```

The result should be:

```py
indexedMaxList = [3, 0, 2, 1, 5, 4]
```

What I tried so far:

```py
def ClusteringOrder(maxList):
    sortedMaxList = maxList.copy()
    sortedMaxList.sort(reverse=True)
    indexedMaxList = []
    for i in range(len(maxList)):
        indexedMaxList.append(maxList.index(sortedMaxList[i]))
    return(indexedmaxList)
```

Problem is obviously, doing it this way returns the index of the first occurrence of duplicate values. In this case, the double 3 will return a 1 two times, hence the result will be:

```py
indexedMaxList = [3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 4]
```

Is there any simple way of doing this to get the actual positions back?

Comment: You can use `numpy.argsort` if you're open to using `numpy`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486252/is-it-possible-to-use-argsort-in-descending-order. In your case: `indexedMaxList  = np.argsort([7, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3])[::-1][:n].tolist()`

Comment: Almost duplicate of [How to get indices of a sorted array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422700/how-to-get-indices-of-a-sorted-array-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine `enumerate()` with custom `key=` parameter in `sorted()`:

```
maxList = [7, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3]

print([i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(maxList), key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)])
```

Prints:

```
[3, 0, 2, 1, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import numpy
maxList = [7, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3]
print(np.flip(np.argsort(maxList)))
```

Output

```
[3 0 2 5 1 4]
```