# How to get index from a natural sort?

Tags: python, indexing, natural-sort

I have a list like

```
mylist=['foo/2.py','foo/12.py','foo/10.py','foo/1.py','foo/25.py']
```

and i need to get the index of the sort like

```
[3,2,1,0,4]
```

The answers of [How to get indices of a sorted array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422700/how-to-get-indices-of-a-sorted-array-in-python) question's are not working as it get the index of a non natural sort

```
def natural_keys(text):
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split(r'(\d+)', text) ]

mylist=['foo/2.py','foo/12.py','foo/10.py','foo/1.py','foo/25.py']
print(mylist)
mylist.sort(key=natural_keys)
print(mylist)
ind=[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(mylist), key=lambda x:x[1])]
print(ind)
mylist=[mylist[i] for i in ind]
print(mylist)
```

gives

```
['foo/2.py', 'foo/12.py', 'foo/10.py', 'foo/1.py', 'foo/25.py']
['foo/1.py', 'foo/2.py', 'foo/10.py', 'foo/12.py', 'foo/25.py']
[0, 2, 3, 1, 4]
['foo/1.py', 'foo/10.py', 'foo/12.py', 'foo/2.py', 'foo/25.py']
```

Comment: Why are you changing the order of the items before finding `ind`?  Remove that step and this should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`natsort`](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) package to achieve the natural sorting part.

```
from natsort import index_natsorted

mylist = ['foo/2.py','foo/12.py','foo/10.py','foo/1.py','foo/25.py']
ind = index_natsorted(mylist)
```

Results in `[3, 0, 2, 1, 4]` vs `[3, 2, 1, 0, 4]` with the default sort.

Comment: Actually, using [`index_natsorted`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#index-natsorted) gives this directly. I was going to answer with this information, but I'll let you update this answer with that.

Comment: As a bonus, to use the index to sort other lists you can use [`order_by_index`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#order-by-index).

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
mylist=['foo/2.py','foo/12.py','foo/10.py','foo/1.py','foo/25.py']
#print([mylist.index(i) for i in sorted(mylist)])
print([mylist.index(i) for i in sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: re.search(r"(\d+)\.py", x).group(1))])
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 2, 1, 0, 4]
```

Comment: YES ! this is it ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Believe me or not. This is the slowest method

Comment: This will not give the correct results if there are duplicate entries in the original list.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach:

```
mylist=['foo/2.py','foo/12.py','foo/10.py','foo/1.py','foo/25.py']

print([i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(mylist), key=lambda k: k[1])])
```

Prints:

```
[3, 2, 1, 0, 4]
```

---

EDIT: If you want to sort by number inside the string, you can do:

```
mylist=['foo/2.py','foo/12.py','foo/10.py','foo/1.py','foo/25.py']
import re
print([i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(int(re.findall(r'\d+', v)[0]) for v in mylist), key=lambda k: k[1])])
```

Prints:

```
[3, 0, 2, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you create a mapping between the list elements and their position first

```
>>> mapping = {k:i for i,k in enumerate(mylist)}
>>> [mapping[k] for k in sorted(mylist)]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 4]
```

To get the indexes when sorted in natural order, you can feed in a custom key to `sorted`

```
>>> import re
>>> [mapping[k] for k in sorted(mylist, key=lambda word: tuple(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', word))))]
[3, 0, 2, 1, 4]
```