# Sorting List according to values and if same value sorting it with index

Tags: python, c++, c, list, sorting

I would like to sort a give list like shown below

input :-`[0,0,1,0,2]`

after sorting i want a list like this
`[1,2,4,3,5]`

As we can see if the list have same values it will compare according to the index.

An Another example of my question, input:`[5,3,6,4,6]` the output must be `[3,1,4,2,5]`

What is the best way to obtain the result ?? Thank you in advance.

Comment: second one should be [2,4,1,3,5] right not [3,1,4,2,5] ?

Comment: no for input [5,3,6,4,6] as 3 is smallest followed by 4 and 5 so output shall be [3,1,4,2,5]

Comment: I am confused, You are outputting the index starting from 1 , isn't it?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `3` is in position 2, `4` in position 4, `5` in position 1 etc...

Comment: Python dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6422700/12416453

Comment: C++ dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1577475/12416453

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get indices of a sorted array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422700/how-to-get-indices-of-a-sorted-array-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Create a pair from `[0,0,1,0,1]` with index starting from 1 like `[(1,0),(2,0), (3,1)...]`, after that sort by the seconds element ex: `0` in `(1,0)`, then lastly take the first element.

```py
l = [0,0,1,0,2]

[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(l,1), key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

```
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```