# Get another row of a matrix according to another ordered row in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors `x` and `y`.

```
    x = c(2, 4, 6, 3, 1.5)
    y = c(2.2, 1, .5)
    m = matrix(c(x, y, rep(0, length(x)), rep(1, length(y))), 
    nrow = 2, ncol= length(x) + length(y), byrow = TRUE)
```

How can I sort the second row of matrix `m` according to sort of first row of matrix `m`in R?

```
    > res
   [1] 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `order`. [Understanding the order() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315601/understanding-the-order-function-in-r) explains some of the details

```
m[2,order(m[1,])]
```