# Wrong order result inside data.table function

Tags: r, data.table

I have found that inside data.table(), order function enumerates rows by groups, while the original idea is to see rank of each observation inside specified groups.

Here is a reproducable example:

```
require(data.table)
N <- 10

set.seed(1)

test <- data.table(
  a = round(rnorm(N,mean=0, sd = 30),0),
  b = c(rep('group_1', N/2 ),rep('group_2', N/2))
)
test <- test[, item_position := order(a, decreasing = T), by=list(b)]
setkey(test, b, item_position)
View(test)
```

The result (as I get it):

```
test
      a       b item_position
 1:  48 group_1             1
 2: -25 group_1             2
 3:  10 group_1             3
 4: -19 group_1             4
 5:   6 group_1             5
 6:  -9 group_2             1
 7:  22 group_2             2
 8: -25 group_2             3
 9:  15 group_2             4
10:  17 group_2             5
```

Which is obviously wrong. 
What am I doing wrong, and how can I use order() inside data.table?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you are actually looking for `rank` not `order`. Perhaps something like: `test[, item_position := rank(a, ties.method="first"), by = b][]`?

Comment: @eddi, the funny thing is that they did use `set.seed` but I get totally different results :-)

Comment: @eddie Sorry, my bad, fixed the result. It's still not what I expect, but I hope this time it matches:)

Comment: @AnandaMahto +1, your solution works, but I still don't understand why wouldn't order() work the way I expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a bit of a misunderstanding of what `order` does. From everything you describe, you're actually looking for `rank`:

```
test[, B_S := rank(-a, ties.method="first"), by = b][] ## Big to Small
#       a       b B_S
#  1: -19 group_1   4
#  2:   6 group_1   3
# .. SNIP ..
#  9:  17 group_2   2
# 10:  -9 group_2   4
test[, S_B := rank(a, ties.method="first"), by = b][]  ## Small to big
#       a       b B_S S_B
#  1: -19 group_1   4   2
#  2:   6 group_1   3   3
# .. SNIP ..
#  9:  17 group_2   2   4
# 10:  -9 group_2   4   2
setkey(test, b, S_B)
test
#       a       b B_S S_B
#  1: -25 group_1   5   1
#  2: -19 group_1   4   2
#  3:   6 group_1   3   3
#  4:  10 group_1   2   4
#  5:  48 group_1   1   5
#  6: -25 group_2   5   1
#  7:  -9 group_2   4   2
#  8:  15 group_2   3   3
#  9:  17 group_2   2   4
# 10:  22 group_2   1   5
```

---

There was nothing *wrong* with the order output (except that it wasn't what you expected). Consider the following:

```
x <- c(-19, 6, -25, 48, 10)
order(x, decreasing=TRUE)
# [1] 4 5 2 1 3
cbind(x, order(x, decreasing=TRUE))
#        x  
# [1,] -19 4
# [2,]   6 5
# [3,] -25 2
# [4,]  48 1
# [5,]  10 3
```

This is exactly the same as what you were getting in your `data.table` answer. To view more about the `order` function, check out this Q and A set: [Understanding the order() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2315601/1270695)

Answer (score 1):

Ananda's solution is the way to go for smaller datasets. For larger ones, where speed becomes an issue, you'll probably want to use `data.table`'s `setkey` instead:

```
test[, idx := .I]            # save index to reorder later
setkey(test, b, a)           # order the way we want
test[, pos := 1:.N, by = b]  # save the positions per group
setkey(test, idx)            # back to original order
```

Comment: you can probably also use the internal fast order functions directly (instead of resorting to `setkey`), but I don't really know which of those functions to use when