# Sorting of data frame in R

Tags: r

I tried sorting data frame in R but unable to do so. I have data frame of 4 columns and would like to sort the data frame from 1st column. Any idea, how Can i sort data frame from entries of first column?

Comment: See `?order`. That should get you started. There are plenty of similar questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [?order](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html) (see also [here](http://www.statmethods.net/management/sorting.html), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058890/1217536)).  Consider:

```
set.seed(5443)
(my.data <- data.frame(y=rnorm(5), 
                      x1=c(1:5), 
                      x2=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                      X3=letters[1:5]))
#             y x1    x2 X3
# 1 -0.15321836  1  TRUE  a
# 2 -0.31570803  2  TRUE  b
# 3 -0.08600789  3 FALSE  c
# 4  1.83347490  4 FALSE  d
# 5 -0.96730746  5 FALSE  e
(my.data <- my.data[order(my.data[,1]),])
#             y x1    x2 X3
# 5 -0.96730746  5 FALSE  e
# 2 -0.31570803  2  TRUE  b
# 1 -0.15321836  1  TRUE  a
# 3 -0.08600789  3 FALSE  c
# 4  1.83347490  4 FALSE  d
```

Comment: How come the first column is different after order is applied?

Comment: (I must have mis-copied somehow. It's fixed now.) All columns are in a different order, @QuantTrader. See the links for how `order` works & how to sort.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(my.data)` and set the 'key' as "y"

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my.data, key = "y")
my.data
#            y x1    x2 X3
#1: -0.96730746  5 FALSE  e
#2: -0.31570803  2  TRUE  b
#3: -0.15321836  1  TRUE  a
#4: -0.08600789  3 FALSE  c
#5:  1.83347490  4 FALSE  d
```

NOTE: data taken from @gung's post.