# Counting cumulative unique occurence in a R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on a data set, which has two columns: id, date/time. Please find the example below,

```
id  date_time
1   2016-10-29 18:01:03.0000000 +08:00
1   2016-10-29 19:34:17.0000000 +08:00
1   2016-10-30 14:08:03.0000000 +08:00
1   2016-10-30 15:55:12.0000000 +08:00
2   2016-10-31 11:32:12.0000000 +08:00
2   2016-10-31 14:59:56.0000000 +08:00
2   2016-11-01 12:49:44.0000000 +08:00
2   2016-11-01 13:55:16.0000000 +08:00
2   2016-11-01 19:18:22.0000000 +08:00
2   2016-11-01 20:40:48.0000000 +08:00
3   2016-11-01 21:19:50.0000000 +08:00
3   2016-11-02 14:20:15.0000000 +08:00
3   2016-11-02 18:52:27.0000000 +08:00
3   2016-11-02 19:39:32.0000000 +08:00
3   2016-11-03 08:55:41.0000000 +08:00
```

All I wanted to obtain is two columns such that: column 1 has cumulative occurrences for each id ordered using date and time  and column 2 has cumulative dates for each id as shown in the table below,

```
id  date_time                           occ date
1   2016-10-29 18:01:03.0000000 +08:00  1   1
1   2016-10-29 19:34:17.0000000 +08:00  2   1
1   2016-10-30 14:08:03.0000000 +08:00  3   2
1   2016-10-30 15:55:12.0000000 +08:00  4   2
2   2016-10-31 11:32:12.0000000 +08:00  1   1
2   2016-10-31 14:59:56.0000000 +08:00  2   1
2   2016-11-01 12:49:44.0000000 +08:00  3   2
2   2016-11-01 13:55:16.0000000 +08:00  4   2
2   2016-11-01 19:18:22.0000000 +08:00  5   2
2   2016-11-01 20:40:48.0000000 +08:00  6   2
3   2016-11-01 21:19:50.0000000 +08:00  1   1
3   2016-11-02 14:20:15.0000000 +08:00  2   2
3   2016-11-02 18:52:27.0000000 +08:00  3   2
3   2016-11-02 19:39:32.0000000 +08:00  4   2
3   2016-11-03 08:55:41.0000000 +08:00  5   3
```

1. (Note that +8:00 is there as a redundant). To generate column 1 (`occ`): I have tried using `ave` with `FUN=seq_along` by first splitting date and time, followed by `order` using id, date and time.

   **Q1**: Is there any way I can directly sort the date_time column ?
2. For column 2(date), I have first taken a subset of the data frame, using unique value I am generating the index using `ave` and `seq_along`. After that I am merging the two data set in a loop.

   **Q2**: Is there a more efficient method to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear to me what format your `date_time` variable is in.  I am assuming it is `POSIXct`.  I have trimmed off the junk and converted it to that.

```
d <- read.table(text="id,  date_time
1,   2016-10-29 18:01:03.0000000 +08:00
...
3,   2016-11-03 08:55:41.0000000 +08:00", header=TRUE, sep=",")
d$date_time <- as.POSIXct(substr(as.character(d$date_time), 4, 22))
```

At this point you can sort the data frame, including by dates, using [?order](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html) (see also: [Understanding the order() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2315601/1217536)):

```
d <- d[order(d$id, d$date_time),]
```

With the data frame sorted, to count up rows within each `id`, you can use [?tapply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tapply.html).  You can likewise use `tapply` to label unique days by composing `as.character` and `as.Date`, and `as.numeric` and `factor`.  Consider:

```
d$occ  <- unlist(with(d, tapply(id, id, FUN=function(x){ 1:length(x) })))
d$date <- unlist(with(d, tapply(date_time, id, FUN=function(x){ 
                                  x = as.character(as.Date(x))
                                  as.numeric(factor(x, levels=unique(x))) 
                                })))
d
#    id           date_time occ date
# 1   1 2016-10-29 18:01:03   1    1
# 2   1 2016-10-29 19:34:17   2    1
# 3   1 2016-10-30 14:08:03   3    2
# 4   1 2016-10-30 15:55:12   4    2
# 5   2 2016-10-31 11:32:12   1    1
# 6   2 2016-10-31 14:59:56   2    1
# 7   2 2016-11-01 12:49:44   3    2
# 8   2 2016-11-01 13:55:16   4    2
# 9   2 2016-11-01 19:18:22   5    2
# 10  2 2016-11-01 20:40:48   6    3
# 11  3 2016-11-01 21:19:50   1    1
# 12  3 2016-11-02 14:20:15   2    1
# 13  3 2016-11-02 18:52:27   3    1
# 14  3 2016-11-02 19:39:32   4    1
# 15  3 2016-11-03 08:55:41   5    2
```