# The order() function in R is not giving me the right results

Tags: r

I had a dataset I was working with and I wanted to use `order` to sort values in a df column. But I did not get the right results. I checked format, and it was all numeric.

Then I loaded the `mtcars` data set built into R and also did not get the right results, i would like to know why that is:

[image]

Comment: try sort() instead ??

Comment: See `?order` and try `mtcars[order(mtcars$hp),]`.

Comment: I find it implausible that they are not giving you the right results. More likely, you are not interpreting the results correctly. `order()` gives you a permutation of the indices, one which corresponds to the sort order. It doesn't directly sort the data.

Comment: Do you mean `mtcars[order(mtcars$hp),]`?

Comment: `order` returns the ranks of the vector. `sort` returns the sorted vector itself. Notice how `identical(mtcars$hp[order(mtcars$hp)], sort(mtcars$hp))` evaluates to `TRUE`.

Comment: @ngm, `order` does not return the ranks.  `o <- order(x)` returns indexes such that `x[o]` is sorted and that is different than ranks.  `order(o)` or `rank(x)` would be the ranks.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of: [Understanding the order() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2315601/4996248)

Comment: I was interpretting the results wrong. I should have used rank() function instead of order().

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I looked into it more and understood the difference between order() and rank()